# Mysql database table cursor

Tags: mysql, cursors

i have written the function below containing a cursor while executing it an error appears . what' wrong please

```
CREATE PROCEDURE processorders()
BEGIN
   DECLARE ordernumbers CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT * FROM psdms_feature_product 

   dept_rec ordernumbers%ROWTYPE
   o ordernumbers%ROWTYPE

   OPEN ordernumbers
   REPEAT
    FETCH ordernumbers INTO o

    IF (o.id_product ) THEN
      IF (o.id_feature  == 510) THEN
        update    psdms_feature_value_lang t1
        LEFT JOIN psdms_feature_product t2
        ON        t1.id_feature_value = t2.id_feature_value
        SET       value ='95090€'
        WHERE     t2.id_product = 1 
        AND       t2.id_feature = 510
      ELSE
        insert into psdms_feature_value ( id_feature ) values (510);
        insert into psdms_feature_product ( id_feature, id_product , id_feature_value) 
        values (o.id_feature , o.id_product , o.id_feature_value )
      END IF
    END IF

   UNTIL done END REPEAT
   CLOSE ordernumbers
END
END
```

Comment: Please reformat your question so that we can read it properly, and tell us what the error message says.

Comment: Erreur dans la requête (1064): Syntax error near 'END IF END IF UNTIL done END REPEAT CLOSE ordernumbers END' at line 3

Comment: Could it be as simple as the second `END` after `CLOSE ordernumbers`? That doesn't logically seem to have any matching `BEGIN` or equivalent.

Comment: There seem to be a few missing semi-colons ...

Comment: MySQL do not support %ROWTYPE, and of course missed semicolons

Comment: @a_vlad what is its equivalent please ? any suggestion

Comment: just define (and declare) variable for each returned column from cursor - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html

Comment: in order to test i have copied the sample in link  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html , looks at the error that is shown   "Erreur dans la requête (1064): Syntax error near 'DECLARE a CHAR(16) DECLARE b, c INT DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,data' at line 4 "

Answer (score 0):

Better is to avoid cursors.  Remember that SQL loves to do things in bulk, but hates to work with Cursors.

```
UPDATE  psdms_feature_value_lang t1
    JOIN  ordernumbers AS o  ON ...
    LEFT JOIN  psdms_feature_product t2
          ON t1.id_feature_value = t2.id_feature_value SET
    value  ='95090€'
    WHERE  t2.id_product = 1
      AND  t2.id_feature = 510
      AND  o.id_product
      AND  o.id_feature = 510;
INSERT
     INTO  psdms_feature_value ( id_feature ) 
SELECT  510
    FROM  ordernumbers
    WHERE  o.id_product
      AND  o.id_feature = 510;
INSERT
     INTO  psdms_feature_product ( id_feature, id_product, id_feature_value) 
SELECT  o.id_feature , o.id_product , o.id_feature_value
    FROM  ordernumbers
    WHERE  o.id_product
      AND  o.id_feature = 510;
```

Index:

```
ordernumbers: INDEX(id_feature, id_product, id_feature_value)
```

Other notes:

`==` is not proper syntax

What do you mean by `AND id_product`?  It probably tests for non-zero.